# invalid reference format when pull docker image from local harbor

Tags: docker

When I am pull image from my local harbor 2.0.2 using this command in Mac OS:

```
[dolphin@localhost harbor]$ sudo docker pull http://192.168.31.93/dolphin/harbor-portal:v2.0.2
invalid reference format
```

why give me this is `invalid reference format` exceptions? harbor will pull from remote server when local not exists the image `harbor-portal:v2.0.2`? I have config the local harbor replica rule:

[image]

this is the source registry:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Source registry format doesn't look ok at all. I must be the issue

Comment: This is not really an answer to solve the issue. It should have been a comment on the question (otherwise you risk other users to downvote you; that I won't do, given you already have low reputation points)